# Replacing characters in the oracle database value range

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a database in an oracle, I filled in the "Number" fields with numbers starting from "A14602727" to "A14603000" but it turned out that I accidentally typed the symbol A (in Ukrainian) instead of A (in English). And now I when find the command:

```
select number from test where number 'А14602727'
```

...find me nothing. Is it possible somehow with the help of the command to replace all numbers **from "A14602727"** (Ukrainian) **to "A14602727"** (English) ?
I will be grateful for your help!)

Comment: Have you tried `replace` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following trick to convert any character to its base character using **accent-insesitive binary sorting**.

```
select your_col,
       utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort(your_col, 'nls_sort=binary_ai')) converted_col 
from your_table
```

Use it in update statement accordingly.

Cheers!!

Comment: Good stuff, but a small caution: `BINARY_AI` implies `BINARY_CI` (case-insensitive) as well.  I believe such an update would have the side-effect of converting everything to lowercase.

Comment: Yes @MatthewMcPeak, it will be case insensitive. But thought of giving this example for future readers. I think I should mention this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `regexp_replace()`:

```
update test set number = regexp_replace(number, '^Ä', 'A');
```

Regexp `'^Ä'` represents character `'Ä'` at the beginning of the string. I used `'Ä'` to represent the A in Ukrainian: replace this with the correct character that you want to replace.

This can also be done, probably more efficiently, with substr and like:

```
update test set number = 'A' || substr(number, 2) where number like 'Ä%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the simple Oracle REPLACE function:

```
UPDATE test 
SET number = REPLACE(number, 'A', 'A');
```

Replace is taking 3 parameters:

1. String in which you will search for a string to replace (The number column)
2. The string you are searchin gto replace (Ukrainian A)
3. The string you will replace it with (English A)

Here you have a DEMO example.

Also please note that the query in your question:

```
select number from test where number 'А14602727';
```

Is not valid. It should be something like this:

```
select number from test where number like 'А14602727';
```

or like this:

```
select number from test where number = 'А14602727';
```

So first do check that!
Cheers!